# ASP.net MVC demo projects that use View Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, viewmodel, open-source

Just wondering if there are any good projects out there that use View Models. I am trying to get my implementation nailed down for how we are going to use VM's and there seems to be a few cross roads that I am coming up to and am wanting to see how other people handle these.

Big bonus if the project uses ASP.net MVC 2.0.

Cheers
Anthony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best example / sample out there, download numbers: 109459

- [**Nerddinner**](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/)

some other:

- [**ASP.NET MVC 2 - Sample Application**](http://commonlibrarynetmvc.codeplex.com/)
- [**ASP.NET MVC 2 Knowledge Exchange
  inspired by StackOverflow**](http://knowledgeexchange.codeplex.com/)

[**A lot more here**](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?projectSearchText=mvc%202&sortBy=Relevance&licenses=|), make your own choice.

Hope This helps

Comment: Ya i saw this but as far as I am aware there are only a couple of places it uses VM's...

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 2 - Sample Application? I can't see anything but MVC 1.0...

Comment: Sorry, I have made the correction, It is a Blog/CMS application and uses TDD, DDD, Linq2Sql, Model/Code Generation, CommonLibrary.NET as well. It is pointing to the right URL now. my apologies

Answer (score 0):

Try [CodeCampServer](http://codecampserver.codeplex.com/).

> CodeCampServer is a free, open source
>   Code Camp management web application.
>   Built on the ASP.NET MVC Framework,
>   this project was founded by Jeffrey
>   Palermo and has been contributed to by
>   many people over the past year+.
>   CodeCampServer is in active
>   development, and uses MvcContrib.
>
> Built on the ASP.NET MVC Framework,
>   this application is the foundation for
>   the examples of the ASP.NET MVC in
>   Action book from Manning and started
>   by Jeffrey Palermo. Jeffrey serves as
>   Product Owner.

Source is hosted on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/).